# Почему функция выполняется до события 'click'?

Tags: javascript, dom

```
button.addEventListener('click', createErrorMessageField());

function createErrorMessageField() {
dataItems.forEach(element => {
    let errorMessage = document.createElement('div');
    errorMessage.className = 'error-hidden';
    element.after(errorMessage);

    if (element.required === true && element.value === '') {
        errorMessage.innerText = 'This field is required';
        errorMessage.className = addErrorClass;
    }
})
```

}

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему выполнение функции происходит до клика?
прогружается страница и уже я вижу добавленные дивы с классами и т.д

Comment: Потому что вы её вызвали. Уберите скобки

Comment: спасибо огромное, почему-то был уверен, что не было скобок, невнимательный капец)

Answer (score -1):

Потому что ты уже вызываешь эту функцию в обработчике button.addEventListener('click', createErrorMessageField());
Надо написать просто вот так `button.addEventListener('click', createErrorMessageField);`
Или

```
button.addEventListener('click', function () {
createErrorMessageField()
);
```